# I want to make a code to turn "a" into "b", "b" into "c", and so on

Tags: javascript

I'm using JavaScript, up to now my code looks like this:

```
var myText = prompt("Type your sentence.");
var newText = [];

for (var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++) {
     if (i = 'a') {
         newText = myText.replace(/a/g, "b");
    }
    else if (i = 'b') {
        newText = myText.replace(/b/g, "c");
    }
}

console.log(newText);
```

If I type "aba", it returns "bbb", why? What can I change?

Comment: what is your requirement actually?

Comment: You should not edit your solution into the question - this is not how [SO] works.. You should click the "tick" to accept the correct answer to mark it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var myText = 'aba';
var newText = "";

for (var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++) {

 if (myText[i] === 'a') {
     newText += "b";
}
else if (myText[i] === 'b') {
    newText += "c";
}
}

console.log(newText);
```

You're using the `=` operator which assigns the value to `i`, even in a conditional statement.  It needs to be `==` or even better `===` as those are the comparison operators. Also you don't want to compare `i`, you want to compare the character at `myText[i]`.

Comment: I tried and it worked, going to try with other letters now. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your syntax for using comparison is wrong. The operator to be used is == or ===. Secondly, you are making a comparison of the looping variable with 'a' or 'b' which is logically wrong since the character at the index should be compared rather than the loop variable. Code snippet for your requirement :

```
var myText = "someinputstring";
var newText = "";

for (var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++) {
    if (myText[i] >= 'a' && myText[i] <= 'z') {            
        var n = myText.charCodeAt(i) + 1;
        if(n == 123) { n = 97; } // When character is 'z' it should be
                                 // replaced by 'a'
        newText = newText + String.fromCharCode(n);
    }
    else { // for anything other than 'a' to 'z'
        newText = newText + myText[i];
    }
}
console.log(newText);
```

Answer (score -1):

And there is a logic failure:
i is a number and the number can't be a string ... instead try to
use

```
    var myText = prompt("Type your sentence.");
    var newText = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++) {
        if(myText.substring(i,i+1) == "a"){
            newText +=  myText.replace(/a/g, "b");
        }
        else if(myText.substring(i,i+1) == "a"){
           newText += myText.replace(/b/g, "c");
        }
    }

    console.log(newText);
```

or better use switch:

```
    var myText = prompt("Type your sentence.");
    var newText = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < myText.length; i++) {
            switch(myText[i]){
                case "a":
                newText += "b";
                break;
                case "b":
                newText += "c";
                break;
            }
        }

console.log(newText);
```